# How do I change Colorbox's description from the title attribute to alt?

Tags: jquery

Basically, I'm using the title attribute for the Tooltip, and I would like to change the description of the image in Colorbox from title to alt instead. I've found some solutions, but they've to do with the Wordpress plugin, and I'm trying to do it on a website.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements

$(".group1").colorbox({rel:"group1", transition:"elastic", maxHeight:"90%", scalePhotos:true});

});

$(function() {
$(".thumb").tooltip({
position: {
my: "center bottom-20",
at: "center top",
using: function( position, feedback ) {
$( this ).css( position );
$( "<div>" )
.addClass( "arrow" )
.addClass( feedback.vertical )
.addClass( feedback.horizontal )
.appendTo( this );
}
}
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mosaic-block bar">
<a class="group1" href="images/AMAASb.jpg" title="As Much Art As Science.">
<img src="images/AMAASs.png" title="Title: As Much Art As Science. TEXTTEXET" border="0" 
style="width: 100%;" class="thumb"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any tooltip library?

Comment: Pretty sure if the title attribute is left out, it uses the alt instead

Answer (score 4):

Pulled almost directly from the colorbox usage guidelines:

```
// Colorbox can accept a function in place of a static value:
$("a.gallery").colorbox({title: function(){
  return $(this).attr('alt');
}});
```

Oh, it looks like you need to pull the alt from an image inside the link.  So you would need to query the children of the anchor tag.  Maybe something like this:

```
$(this).children('img').attr('alt');
```

Comment: Just tried it out, replaced "a.gallery" with "a.group1", but the description still doesn't show up.

Comment: did you change your html?  Because your original post did not have an alt attribute anywhere.  I would suggest using the console to output values to hone in on the correct one.

Comment: Yup, I did change my HTML as well. I tried the original solution, and it seems that worked. Apologies, it seems I didn't read the usage carefully enough!